# Spring Authorization Server returns access_denied after granting consent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I tried setting up a very minimal Spring Authorization Server example as part of evaluating it for use in one of my projects. The Authorization Server will be used with a SPA application so the Authorization Code flow with PKCE will be used. I am using Spring Boot 3.2.0.

The example application is generated by [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and consists of a single configuration file to set up the minimal requirements for an Authorization server that largely follows the ["How-To" from the official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/reference/guides/how-to-pkce.html)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                );

        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()
                )
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient publicClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("public-client")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:4200")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(true)
                        .requireProofKey(true)
                        .build()
                )
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(publicClient);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
    {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://127.0.0.1:4200");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
}
```

When making a properly formed request to the `/authorize` endpoint I am redirected to the default login page as expected.
[image: Spring Authorization Server default log in page]

For the sake of completeness the example request that redirects me to this login page looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=public-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&state=1234xyz&code_challenge=cFeDr-CjSa6l1C3w388Qoz1GpM3Pa0qzkOF9rq0Wp8A&code_challenge_method=S256` using a code challenge and verifier generated by [PKCE Tools](https://example-app.com/pkce)

When entering valid user credentials (as configured in the configuration above) I am redirected to the consent screen as expected.
[image: Spring Authorization Server consent screen]

However, upon granting consent by selecting the "Submit Consent" button I get an "access_denied" error returned in the redirect url. The url that gets redirected to is
`http://127.0.0.1:4200/?error=access_denied&error_description=OAuth%202.0%20Parameter%3A%20client_id&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdatatracker.ietf.org%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Frfc6749%23section-4.1.2.1&state=1234xyz`

This includes the error message "access_denied" and error description "OAuth 2.0 Parameter: client_id" and points me to [a section of the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1) which does not contain any further useful information for troubleshooting this specific error message.

Ostensibly, the error description indicates that Spring thinks there is something wrong with the client_id but I fail to see what could be wrong with it.

Which piece of the puzzle am I missing here that is causing me to receive this error for a valid user who has successfully authenticated and chosen to give their consent?

**EDIT 2024-02-19**

I noticed when revisiting this that my request to the authorization server was using `127.0.0.1` while my redirect was using `localhost`. I have since corrected this so that both the request and redirect use the same exact host and have tested it by trying out both hosts of `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`. However, the results when using either host in a consistent manner were the same as described in the original question and I am still receiving the "access_denied" error.

The question has been updated to show the use of `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced with the same issue, and after some investigations, found that it needed to add additional scope (I had only scope(OidcScopes.OPENID) before) in registeredClientRepository method like

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient publicClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("public-client")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:4200")
            .scope("your-scope")
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                    .requireAuthorizationConsent(true)
                    .requireProofKey(true)
                    .build()
            )
            .build();
```

And then add it to request's parameters as:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=public-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&state=1234xyz&code_challenge=cFeDr-CjSa6l1C3w388Qoz1GpM3Pa0qzkOF9rq0Wp8A&code_challenge_method=S256&scope=your-scope

I hope it will help you.